# Filter listview with spinner then searchbox (edittext)

Tags: android, listview, filter, spinner

I have a listview with cars such as car name, some details of the car. I would like to find a car by its name.

1. I filter the cars by its current status(run, stop, ...) using Android spinner
2. Then, I type in the search box(using editetext) next to the Spinner the car's name. It should filter the car(s) with status choose in the Spinner.

I know how to do them separately but not together. How can I combine both spinner filter and search filter together? Really appreciate the help!

[CarlistFragment1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3dof.png)     [CarListFragment2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S62TZ.png)

Car(Model) I have setter and getter method as normal when creating a listview.

CarAdapter code:

```
//This car list adapter class provides data to list view
public class CarListAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable{

    private Context context;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List<Car> carList; // Original Data
    private List<Car> carListSpinnerFiltered; // spinner filtered data
    //private List<Car> carListSearchFiltered;  // search filtered data
    private ValueFilter valueFilter;
    private ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();

    public CarListAdapter(Context context, List<Car> carList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.carList = carList;
        this.carListSpinnerFiltered = carList;
        //this.carListSearchFiltered  = carList;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return carList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return carList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
//        return position;
        return carList.indexOf(getItem(position));
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (inflater == null)
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null)
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row_carlist, null);

        if (imageLoader == null)
            imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();
        NetworkImageView thumbNail = (NetworkImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.car_image);

        TextView devname  = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.devname);
        TextView location = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.location);
        TextView status   = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.status);
        TextView speed    = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.speed);

        // getting vehicle data for the row
        final Car c = carList.get(position);

        // thumbnail image
//        thumbNail.setImageUrl(c.getImageURL(), imageLoader);

        // device name
        devname.setText(c.getDevname());

        // location
        if (c.getLocation().equals("")) {
            location.setText(String.valueOf("Location unknown"));
        } else {
            location.setText(String.valueOf(c.getLocation()));
        }

        // status
            switch (c.getStatus()) {
                case "run":
                    status.setText(String.valueOf(statusRun));
                    status.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context.getApplicationContext(), R.color.colorCarRun));
                    break;

                case "stop":
                    status.setText(String.valueOf(statusStop));
                    status.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context.getApplicationContext(), R.color.colorCarStop));
                    break;

                case "lost_gprs":
                    status.setText(String.valueOf(statusLostGprs));
                    status.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context.getApplicationContext(), R.color.colorBlack));
                    break;

                case "lost_gps":
                    status.setText(String.valueOf(statusLostGps));
                    status.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context.getApplicationContext(), R.color.colorffbf00));
                    break;

                case "expired":
                    status.setText(String.valueOf("Expired"));
                    status.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context.getApplicationContext(), R.color.colorBlue));
                    break;
            }

        // speed
        speed.setText(String.valueOf(c.getSpeed()));

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        if (valueFilter == null) {
            valueFilter = new ValueFilter();
        }
        return valueFilter;
    }

    private class ValueFilter extends Filter {

        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();


            // Search Field
//            if (constraint != null && constraint.length() > 0 ) {
//                ArrayList<Car> filterList = new ArrayList<>();
//
//                for (int i = 0; i < carListSearchFiltered.size(); i++) {
//
//                    String devname = carListSearchFiltered.get(i).getDevname().toUpperCase();
//                    String inputString = constraint.toString().toUpperCase();
//
//                    if (devname.contains(inputString)) {
//                        Car car = new Car();
//                        car.setDevname(carListSearchFiltered.get(i).getDevname());
//                        car.setLocation(carListSearchFiltered.get(i).getLocation());
//                        car.setStatus(carListSearchFiltered.get(i).getStatus());
//                        car.setSpeed(carListSearchFiltered.get(i).getSpeed());
//                        car.setDevid(carListSearchFiltered.get(i).getDevid());
//                        filterList.add(car);
//                    }
//
//
//                } // end for loop
//
//                results.count = filterList.size();
//                results.values = filterList;
//
//            } else {
//                results.count = carListSearchFiltered.size();
//                results.values = carListSearchFiltered;
//            }



            // Spinner Filter
            String inputStatus = constraint.toString();

            if (!inputStatus.equals("All")) {

                ArrayList<Car> spinnerList = new ArrayList<>();

                for (int i = 0; i < carListSpinnerFiltered.size(); i++){
                    String carStatus = carListSpinnerFiltered.get(i).getStatus();

                    switch (carStatus){
                        case "run":
                            carStatus = "run";
                            break;

                        case "stop":
                            carStatus = "stop";
                            break;

                        case "lost_gprs":
                            carStatus = "lost_gprs";
                            break;

                        case "lost_gps":
                            carStatus = "lost_gps";
                            break;

                        default:
                            Toast.makeText(context, "status unknown", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            break;

                    } // end switch

                    if (carStatus.equals(inputStatus)) {

                        Car car = new Car();
                        car.setDevname(carListSpinnerFiltered.get(i).getDevname());
                        car.setLocation(carListSpinnerFiltered.get(i).getLocation());
                        car.setStatus(carListSpinnerFiltered.get(i).getStatus());
                        car.setSpeed(carListSpinnerFiltered.get(i).getSpeed());
                        car.setDevid(carListSpinnerFiltered.get(i).getDevid());
                        spinnerList.add(car);

                    }

                } // end for loop

                results.count = spinnerList.size();
                results.values = spinnerList;

            } else {

                results.count = carListSpinnerFiltered.size();
                results.values = carListSpinnerFiltered;
            }

            return results;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            carList = (List<Car>) results.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

    } // end class

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first issue I notice is that you're overwriting your original list of cars, stored in `carList`, with the filter results. That means when the filter's cleared you won't be able to restore them.

You might find it easier if you keep one list for the original set of data, and another list for the data that you'll be displaying. Initially these will be the same. Then in `performFilter` you can recreate the display list with cars you want from the full list.

For your actual question, it doesn't look like the `Filter` class can handle multiple constraint types. If you're set on using it, you would need your filter to do both types of filtering every time `performFilter` was called. You could create your own methods on your adapter that take in both a status filter from your spinner and a text filter from you search box and join them with a special character, like `|`. Example:

`lost_gps|mysearch`

Then separate them in the `performFilter()` method.

Another point is that your switch statement in `performFilter` is effectively just displaying a Toast if the status isn't known. None of the assignments do anything, it could be replaced by an `if` statement where you test against each of the statuses, or even better if the statuses were in a premade `HashSet` object and then you could just use `Set.contains()`.

Update:

To flesh out the idea more, in your adapter you would have something like

```
class Adapter ... {
    private String mStatusFilter = "";
    private String mSearchFilter = "";

    private void setStatusFilter(String statusFilter) {
        mStatusFilter = statusFilter;
        getFilter().filter(mStatusFilter + "|" + mSearchFilter);
    }

    private void setSearchFilter(String searchFilter) {
        mSearchFilter = searchFilter;
        getFilter().filter(mStatusFilter + "|" + mSearchFilter);
    }
}
```

Then in your Filter class

```
performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
   displayedCarList.clear();
   String statusFilter = constraint.split("|")[0]
   String searchFilter = constraint.split("|")[1]
   for(Car car: carList) {
       // Does it match the status? (if filter not set, default to yes)
       boolean statusMatch = TextUtils.isEmpty(statusFilter) ||
            car.status.equals(statusFilter);
       // Does it match the name? (if filter not set, default to yes)
       boolean searchMatch = TextUtils.isEmpty(searchFilter) ||
            car.name.contains(searchFilter);
       if(statusMatch && searchMatch) {
           displayedCarList.add(car)
       }
   }
   ...
}
```

The adapter would just display all the cars in `displayedCarList`.

Comment: Thank you for your comment but I still don't really understand it much. I cant implement both filters at the same time. The spinner is to show all cars with current selected status. Only then is user want to filter a specific car within the spinner result. The problem is performingFilter() only take one constraint. How can I filter listview with multiple constraint seperately? This is hard. I can't solve this man!

Comment: I fleshed out my idea in code a bit, does that help? Can you explain more which part you don't understand?

Comment: I am still trying

Comment: Your code here is to show that performFiltering() takes in 2 constraints at the same time right? What I need is after the first constraint(as in my code, the car status) listview filtered once. And then I add in another constraint and it filter one more time along with the first constraint.